# How can I round down how many asterisks are printed in this code?

Tags: java, loops

An assignment I am working on is asking me to modify a bar chart program they provided me with. So far I think I've got everything correct, although it specifies that "if a player has scored 48 points, then display four asterisks." However, my code displays five asterisks when a player has scored 48 points. How can I make it so that it only displays 4 asterisks? My instructor mentioned using integer division in my for loop which I did use, but that did not work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BarChart2 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int artPoints;
        int bobPoints;
        int calPoints;
        int danPoints;
        int eliPoints;
        final int AMT_EACH_ASTERISK = 10;
        System.out.println("Enter points earned for the season");
        System.out.print("    by Art >> ");
        artPoints = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("    by Bob >> ");
        bobPoints = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("    by Cal >> ");
        calPoints = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("    by Dan >> ");
        danPoints = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("    by Eli >> ");
        eliPoints = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\nPoints for Season (each asterisk represents " +
                           AMT_EACH_ASTERISK + " points)\n");

        drawChart("Art", artPoints, AMT_EACH_ASTERISK);
        drawChart("Bob", bobPoints, AMT_EACH_ASTERISK);
        drawChart("Cal", calPoints, AMT_EACH_ASTERISK);
        drawChart("Dan", danPoints, AMT_EACH_ASTERISK);
        drawChart("Eli", eliPoints, AMT_EACH_ASTERISK);
    }
    public static void drawChart(String name, int points, int amt_each) { // Main issue here
              System.out.print(name + ":  ");
        int numAsterisks = points / amt_each;
      for(numAsterisks = 0; numAsterisks < points; numAsterisks += amt_each)
             System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: How would we know without any knowledge of how `points` and `amt_each` are set? Is it an asterisk for every 10?

Comment: Using a debugger and stepping through each line of the code will definitely help you.

Comment: An asterisk for eery 10, so 37 points would be 3 asterisks, 52 points would be 5 asterisks, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're basically doing the correct calculation (integer division) here: `int numAsterisks = points / amt_each;` (this will result in 48/10 = 4).

However, you are *then* throwing that value away by reinitializing `numAsterisks` to 0 in your loop (`for(numAsterisks = 0; ...)`).

Instead do something like this:

```
for(int i= 0; i < numAsterisks; i++) {
   System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println();
```

Note that I added curly braces to the loop's body to make it clear what belongs into the loop and what doesn't. This is meant to prevent errors that could come from *assuming* that statements like `System.out.println();` would be part of the body because of their indentation.